# Remove Grouping name from Devextreme group column with pagination

Tags: angular, devextreme

#### TL;DR

How to keep the text for content going to next page when removing the column name from the grouping row.

---

#### Problem Explained

I'm using Devextreme datagrid to display data (with pagination) and I noticed that when grouping the data by a column, the group names will always display like so:

```
groupingColumnName: columnValue
```

So for example if I have a table with `ID`, `Name` and say `Age` and decided to group by age, my table will look a little like this:

```
| ID    | Name   |
|----------------|
|Age: 21       v | <---- grouping row (expanded)
|----------------|
| 1     | Elise  | <---- grouping's content
| 5     | Mary   |
|----------------|
|Age: 24       v |
|----------------|
| 2     | Joseph |
|----------------|
|Age: 17       > | <---- grouping row (collapsed)
|----------------|
|----------------|
|Age: 30        v|
|----------------|
| ...            |
```

I tried using `groupCellTemplate` and managed to get the value only, but now I don't get the `(Continues on the next page)` text next to it if the row is expanded but the content goes on the next page, which is usually working by default.

How can I keep the text for content that goes to the next page while removing the name of the column used for grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that once you use the `groupCellTemplate` binding, you have to manually add any text that is usually conditionally displayed, otherwise the grid will always display your template as is.

So you need to add the `(Continues on the next page)` or `(Continued from previous page)` text yourself when needed.

The way I did it was using the `groupContinuedMessage` and `groupContinuesMessage` properties. Those are usually undefined, so if they aren't I can just append them to my grouping's row text:

#### template

```
<dxi-column 
  [groupCellTemplate]="formatGroupCell" 
  caption="Age"
  dataField="Age" 
  [groupIndex]="0">
</dxi-column>
```

#### .ts

```
formatGroupCell(elem, data) {
    let formattedValue = data.displayValue;
    formattedValue += data.groupContinuedMessage ? ` (${data.groupContinuedMessage}) ` : ''
    formattedValue += data.groupContinuesMessage ? ` (${data.groupContinuesMessage}) ` : ''
    elem.append(formattedValue);  
  }
```

*Or all in the template:*

```
<dxi-column 
  [groupCellTemplate]="groupCellTemplate" 
  caption="Age"
  dataField="Age" 
  [groupIndex]="0">
</dxi-column>
<div *dxTemplate="let data of 'groupCellTemplate'">
   {{data.displayValue}}
   {{data.groupContinuesMessage ? ' ('+data.groupContinuesMessage+')' : ''}} 
   {{data.groupContinuedMessage ? ' ('+data.groupContinuedMessage+')': ''}}
</div>
```

Now I don't have to see the name of the column used for grouping and I can still use pagination and know when content carries over on the next page.